# Virtual machine lost after power cut

Tags: virtual-machines, electrical-power, vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

We have just had a power issue and our ESX (ESXi 4.1.0) host lost power and then rebooted. All but one of the virtual servers have rebooted with no problem, however one of them refused to power up.

I try to power it on and I get the following error:

```
File <unspecified filename> was not found
Reason: The system cannot find the file specified.
Cannot open the disk '/vmfs/volumes/4e03076e-90834647-b846-001185c38f42/LAMP-   Stack/turnkey-lamp-11.3-lucid-x86.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on. 
VMware ESX cannot find the virtual disk "/vmfs/volumes/4e03076e-90834647-b846-  001185c38f42/LAMP-Stack/turnkey-lamp-11.3-lucid-x86.vmdk". Verify the path is valid and try again.
```

I have logged into the ESX host to see if the file is there an have found only the following file that matches the filename:

```
/vmfs/volumes/4e03076e-90834647-b846-001185c38f42/LAMP-Stack/turnkey-lamp-11.3-l                  ucid-x86-s001.vmdk
```

I notice that the above file has '-s001' after the filename. Is this recoverable?

Any help of advice is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Running ls -l on the directory that contains the file shows this:

```
drwxr-xr-t  1 root root  1680 Feb  9 09:49 4e03076e-90834647-b846-001185c38f42
```

The databrowser file system looks like this:

[image: databrowser]

and in a different directory there is the file that matches the missing one:

[image: file]

Comment: On a side note; that's one of the reasons why I like using LVM volumes as VM disk back-ends. Files are too precarious. (I have no experience with VMWare though, I mostly use Xen on LInux).

Answer (score 2):

That single file is only a snapshot. If that is the only file you have for this VM...you won't be able to restore it.  Where are the other VMDK and VMX files? Go into the directory (volume) "4e03076e-90834647-b846-001185c38f42" that you show in the screen shot and do an ls -l there and show us the output.

Depending on what is still available in that volume, I would suggest removing the VM from inventory and adding it back in. You will need a .vmx file to do this.

In addition, can you provide the ESXi log files which are available via DCUI (console) or SSH: [Location of ESXi 3.5-4.1 log files](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1021801). Good log files would be Messages (/var/log/messages) and Hostd.log (/var/log/vmware/hostd.log)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if the contents of this VM are really important (ie, not something you can just rebuild in a few days), then you need to turn off the machine, take out the disk drives and back up full images of all of the disks (including parts marked as free space) with a disk imaging tool, *right now*, before you do *anything* else. Every time the filesystem is written to, there is a significant risk that lost files will be rendered permanently unrecoverable.

Now, assuming this is a VM that could be rebuilt with some inconvenience and isn't holding the only copy of vital data, you might try seeing if the file, or other related files, exist elsewhere in the filesystem:

```
find / -iname 'turnkey-lamp-11.3-lucid*'
```

If the filesystem was slightly corrupted, then files whose correct location couldn't be determine might've been moved to 'lost+found'. There will be one such directory per mounted disk; so to find them all, use

```
find / -name 'lost+found'
```

And take a look inside for any multi-gigabyte files. If you find anything that might be your disk image, then first back it up, then copy it to the location where vmware is expecting to find it and try booting.